# Web method with ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I am facing a really strange situation. I have a **JavaScript** file :

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.8.2.min.js" />
var compte = 0;
var poste = [];
var posteselectionner = [3];
$(function () {

   jQuery.getJSON("ServiceContactTest.svc/DoWork", null, function () { **//HERE ****

            alert("ds");

   });

   var msg = 1;

   $("#Uploadb").click(function () {

      alert('f');

   });

   $(".test1").click(function () {

      msg = msg + 1;

      $("#li1").html("<a href='#'><img src='images/partners/jquery.png' alt=''></a>");

   });

   $("#info").mouseover(function () {

      $("#info").popover("show");

   });

   $("#info").mouseleave(function () {

      $("#info").popover("hide");

   });

   $("#envoyer").click(function () {

      var erreur = true;

      if (document.getElementById("myFile").value == "") {

         jQuery("#alert2").attr("style", "display:block");
         erreur = false;

      } else {

         jQuery("#alert2").attr("style", "display:none");

      }

      if (compte == 0) {

         jQuery("#alert3").attr("style", "display:block");
         erreur = false;

      } else {

        jQuery("#alert3").attr("style", "display:none");
      }

      if (erreur == true) {

        jQuery.getJSON("ServiceContactTest.svc/DoWork", null, function () {  **//HERE ****

            alert("ds");

        });

        alert('doo3');
      }

    return erreur;

});
```

});

As you can, see I bind some event in the page load. But what I want to point to you is the FIRST call and the SECOND call of the web method :

**1- The first call is running in the page load :**

```
jQuery.getJSON("ServiceContactTest.svc/DoWork", null, function () { **//HERE ****

    alert("ds");

});
```

**2- The second in the `Event Click` of the input "envoyer" :**

```
$("#envoyer").click(function () {

      var erreur = true;

      if (document.getElementById("myFile").value == "") {

         jQuery("#alert2").attr("style", "display:block");
         erreur = false;

      } else {

         jQuery("#alert2").attr("style", "display:none");

      }

      if (compte == 0) {

         jQuery("#alert3").attr("style", "display:block");
         erreur = false;

      } else {

        jQuery("#alert3").attr("style", "display:none");
      }

      if (erreur == true) {

        jQuery.getJSON("ServiceContactTest.svc/DoWork", null, function () {  **//HERE ****

            alert("ds");

        });

        alert('doo3');
      }

    return erreur;

  });
```

**The problem I have is, the first call working very well but the second don't work at all.**

I know the code of the second call don't throw error because the `alert('doo3');` is called.

**Here's my web method-service :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace CvContact
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class ServiceContactTest
    {
       [OperationContract]
       [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
       public void DoWork()
       {
            return;
       }
    }
 }
```

Here's my html :

```
<input id="envoyer" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" runat=server value="Postuler !" ClientIdmode="static" />
```

I really don't know what I am doing wrong. Do you know what can cause that ? Work on the `page load`, but stuck on `Event`.

Comment: FYI  `$(function () {...});` is shortcut for DOM ready, not window onload

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prevent default behaviour on submit button otherwise your page is reload if "erreur" = true:

```
$("#envoyer").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //code here

  if(!erreur)
     $('#myform').trigger('submit');//#myform   because you didn't post your html code
});
```

Comment: ok, it is working BUT the page is not postback AND why do the alrt('doo3'); come before the alert('ds'); ? Thank you

Comment: because $.getJSON() is asynchron. To submit page you have to trigger submit() event of the form. You maybe want to submit form regarding what your getJSON method returns, in this case, submit form inside getJSON callback function. Hope you get the logic.

Comment: Ok, but why the alert('doo3') come before ?

Comment: ya, for sure it comes before! I think you don't really understand what means asynchronous. You should try to find some documentation about it.

Comment: I know what is asynchronous. But that's not explaining why it come after.

Comment: You mean why alert('doo3'); comes before alert('ds'); ?

Comment: If is so evident why it come after, why you don't tell me instead of telling me i am an ignorant. I am just trying to understand. Btw thank you for your help. Yes, alert('doo3') come before the alert('ds');.

Comment: Sorry, but what are talking about? I'm trying to help you by giving you advice, that's all! I never think you were ignorant...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31279/discussion-between-vinc-p-and-roasted)